# Python - Pandas.ExcelFile() return the wrong number in few cases

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am quite new in coding and i face an issue that i can't fix by myself.

I am using Pandas and in the following code the the printed list return 80-90% of the time the right numbers and in few cases a different number coming from nowhere...

My thought were that pandas doesn't read excel really well and i will have to use a csv but i am using multiples tabs in the excel file and i would like to make it work.

Do you have any suggetsion? Thanks a lot!

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the Excel and create a Dataframe
xl = pd.ExcelFile("data_source.xlsx")
df = xl.parse(paris)

# Creating the list of vehicle id and rate plan id
list_vehicle_type_id = df['vehicle_type_id'].dropna().astype('int').abs().tolist()
list_plan_id = df['plan_id'].dropna().astype('int').abs().tolist()

print(list_vehicle_type_id)
print(list_plan_id)
```

I found the issue:

```
# Read the Excel and create a Dataframe
xl = pd.ExcelFile("data_source.xlsx")
df = xl.parse(country_choice)

# Creating the list of vehicle id and rate plan id
list_vehicle_type_id = df['vehicle_type_id'].dropna().astype('int').abs().tolist()

list_plan_id = df['plan_id'].dropna().tolist() # Creating a list of plan id as float
list_plans_int = [] # Creating an empty list
for i in list_plan_id: # Creating a loop to extract the list of plan id as float one by one and add it to the empty list as integer
    id_int =  int(i)
    list_plans_int.append(id_int)
```

Comment: why not using `pandas.read_csv` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html  ??

Comment: wow sorry wrong code i edited it s an excel file

Comment: just to understand why do you use `.dropna()`  ? ,  this could be the problem (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html )

Comment: Do you have a minimial example of values which are not returned correctly? What happens to those values once you temporarily remove `astype('int').abs()`? Perhaps excel stores those values as mixed types and pandas has some trouble converting them properly.

Comment: @Dadep because when i create the df['plan_id'] it return some NaN.

Comment: @pansen i am going to try again but from what i remmber i had some weird number going negative .. My typical id look like '1733481504' and sometime it s just return something diferent coming from nowhere ...

Comment: I don't know but maybe it come from the way to encode (ascii, utf-8, etc...) ...?

Comment: @Dadep i'll have a look at it trying to do some research ...

Comment: @oilid.b Please provide some concrete examples otherwise it is hard to judge where the error is coming from. Another approach is to convert the xlsx file (using excel software) to csv and to have a look at the plain data with an text editor like notepad++. By this, you are going to see the raw values without any excel magic applying to it. In fact, pandas should reveal the same values as the raw csv.